# How to get scales to appear under each facet of ggplot2?

Tags: r

I would like that scales appear under each facet of ggplot2. The graph produced by the following code inserts the scales only in the last facet. It is probably simple but I can't seem to get a handle on this. Below is my R code.

```
ggplot(aes(x=month),data=tot.d.pred ) + 
geom_line(aes(y=tot.diff.pred, colour="tot.diff.pred")) + 
geom_point(aes(y=tot.diff.pred, colour="tot.diff.pred")) +
facet_wrap(~state_code, nrow=3) + ylab("diff_pred") + xlab("Month") +
scale_colour_manual("",breaks=c("tot.diff.pred"), values=c("red"))
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, you don't need the quotes around `"tot.diff.pred"` inside `aes()`.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `scales = "free_x"` inside `facet_wrap` will print x-scales on every facet. If your data already has the same xmin and xmax in each facet, nothing else will change, otherwise you can specify limits with `scale_x_continuous()`.

Comment: Thanks a tonne. As I had guessed pretty simple :-)